# Bash, if find a matched string in file_A, then copy file_B after the matched string in file_A

Tags: file, sed, append, match

Recently, I need to do this job :

Step 1

Finding a matched string in file_A, for instance, the string to be matched is "ILikeeStackoverflow".

> file_A
>
> ......
>
> ILikeStackoverflow
>
> The line after "ILikeStackoverflow"
>
> .......

Step 2

If this string "ILikeeStackoverflow" is existed, then copy another file_B(less than 10 lines) into this file_A, just after that string.

So after doing this copy, file_A should look like this shape :

> file_A
>
> ......
>
> ILikeStackoverflow
>
> Line_1_of_file_B
>
> Line_2_of_file_B
>
> ......
>
> Line_n_of_file_B
>
> The line after "ILikeStackoverflow"
>
> .......

My code is this but can't work properly(Both file_A and file_B in current directory).

```
      match_string="ILikeStackoverflow" 
      sed " /^$match_string/a"$file_B" " file_A
```

Thanks a lot for suggestions !

Edit :

Right now, I know why I was stuck, but can't figure out how to fix the code. Please continue to comment if you have an idea, thanks a lot !

The problem is, only if the string occupied a separate line, sat's code works.  if the matched string is just a part of a long string, then his code can't work. For instance, if fileA is like this, then the code can't work.

> file_A
>
> ......
>
> /test/begin/ILikeStackoverflow/test/end
>
> The line after "ILikeStackoverflow"
>
> .......

Actually, in my "index.html", the string to be matched is : "5000s-IntW300" ,while the line containing my matched string is :

> /blue-ccd-data/DAMIC_SNOLAB_RUN1/5000s-IntW300-OS

Any suggestions to fix it ?

Thanks a lot again !

Edit 2:

Actually, I want to copy fileB in the place of one more line after than matched string line. For instance, the real position would be :

> file_A
>
> ......
>
> /test/begin/ILikeStackoverflow/test/end
>
> The line has an important information and fileB shouldn't be copied here.
>
> This is the exact line of fileB should be copied.
>
> .......

Comment: How are you running **sat's** command? Note that his `^` does a zero-width assertion to begin of line, which is not the case of `5000s-IntW300` in the middle of the line.

Comment: @Birei, You got it ! And me too ! So, when I removed this `^`, it works! However, there is another little but important problem : I will edit my post again !

Comment: So, you want to insert content of the other file two lines after the match, not in the next one. Is always like that or depends in anything else?

Comment: @Birei : Thanks a lot for your response ! It always likes that. Because in my code, the matched line and its next line should not be separated.

Comment: The base from [sat](http://stackoverflow.com/users/874178/sat) answer is useful. You have to add `N` that reads next line before appending the content of `fileB` with the `r` command. It seems that doesn't detect the file inside a group as a one-liner command, so you probably will have to use a file and invoke it using the `-f` switch. If you have problems tell us and I will put it as an answer.

Comment: @Birei, please post your code here. I'm a total newbie in bash coding. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `sed`,

```
sed -i.bak '/matchString/r fileB' fileA
```

**Test:**

**File A**

```
sample
text
Stackoverflow
some
text
```

**File B**

```
Line 1
Line 2
....
Line 10
```

**Output:**

```
sat:~# sed -i.bak '/^Stackoverflow/r FileB' FileA
sample
text
Stackoverflow
Line 1
Line 2
....
Line 10
some
text
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it can't work to me - at least in my script of your code : `sed -i.bak "/^$table_key_words_monitoring_mainpage/r $modified_one_entry_table" index.html`, where `$table_key_words_monitoring_mainpage` is the key word, `$modified_one_entry_table` is file_A, `index.html` is file_B. Any suggestions ?

Comment: @user2740039, looks like you're mixing A and B: `sed -i.bak "/^$table_key_words_monitoring_mainpage/r index.html" $modified_one_entry_table`

Comment: @glennjackman, in my case, I wanted to copy the file of `modified_one_entry_table` into my `index.html` after the key word line of "$table_key_words_monitoring_mainpage". I anyway changed my code as you suggested, but it can't help also. Additionally, it produce the useless file like `modified_one_entry_table.bak`.

Comment: @user2740039, Have you tried with the sample files which i specified in the answer? Can you tell your OS and sed version.

Comment: @sat, your sample files can pass your code test normally on command line and script both. However, it can't be adapted to my script which obviously I cared most. My OS is : openSUSE 12.2, sed is GNU sed version 4.2.1 .

Answer (score 0):

The key is to read a line after the match, and it's done with the `N` command. Then use `r` to insert the whole content of the other file. Originally I tried:

```
sed '/Stackoverflow/ { N; r fileB };' fileA
```

but gives me following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: unmatched `{'
```

So I used a file with the `sed` commands and invoke it using `-f` switch.

Content of `script.sed`:

```
/Stackoverflow/ {
        N
        r fileB
}
```

And run it like:

```
sed -f script.sed fileA
```

Based in the example data of [sat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874178/sat), it yields:

```
sample
text
Stackoverflow
some
Line 1
Line 2
....
Line 10
text
```